# What is the correct return type of Apollo's watchQuery().valueChanges for GraphQL in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, apollo, apollo-client

We are using [Apollo Angular](https://apollo-angular.com/) to connect to a GraphQL API. This works fine. I now wanted to create an API service that abstracts the `watchQuery` method.

This works fine until I add the return type to the method. The type hint says the return type of `valueChanges` is `Observable<ApolloQueryResult<any>>`. But when I add it as the function's return type I get this error:

> Property '['@@observable']' is missing in type 'Observable<ApolloQueryResult>' but required in type 'Observable'.

The suggestions for imports are these three - but none worked and resulted in the same error:

```
import { ApolloQueryResult } from '@apollo/client/core/types';
import { ApolloQueryResult } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { ApolloQueryResult } from '@apollo/client';
```

This is how the service looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Apollo, WatchQueryOptions } from 'apollo-angular';
import { ApolloQueryResult } from '@apollo/client/core/types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiService {
  constructor(
    private apollo: Apollo
  ) { }

  watchQuery(options: WatchQueryOptions<any>): Observable<ApolloQueryResult<any>> {
    return this.apollo.watchQuery<any>(options).valueChanges;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can let typescript infer the return type, e.g remove `: Observable<ApolloQueryResult<any>>`. You can then add it back once you know the correct return type

Comment: Yeah, I have it on `any` at the moment, @MikeS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr: Make sure you add `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';` to your service.

---

In **apollo-angular**, `valueChanges` returns type `Observable` from **rxjs** ([link to source](https://github.com/kamilkisiela/apollo-angular/blob/f3dc3656a29e20172a8c25fa39ffc6da52b278d3/packages/apollo-angular/src/query-ref.ts#L18)).

However, if you *Go to Definition* on the `Observable` declared in your service, it takes you to something **@apollo/client** adds as a global type ([link to source](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/6790be17979072e8c7c9f578ed24a120b19e618b/src/utilities/observables/Observable.ts#L17-L19)).

Now, I don't understand exactly what this global ambient declaration is for. But by not importing the real `Observable` from **rxjs** in your file, your service is declared to return the global **@apollo/client** one, while *actually* returning the **rxjs** one.